# Key from PFObject causing crash -- Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

I'm trying to retrieve a string from a subclass of a `PFObject` like so:

```
  NSLog(@"Name: %@", _post.repost.group.name);

  NSString *dateAuthor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ from group @%@", [_post.repost.createdAt timeAgo], _post.group.name];
```

Getting the following log:

> 2014-05-29 19:39:55.243 Bevy2[1966:60b] BevyTeam
>
> 2014-05-29
>   19:41:02.407 Bevy2[1966:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Key "name" has
>   no data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its value.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x2fbf1f0b 0x3a388ce7 0x2fbf1e4d 0xbfabf 0xc2e69 0x451a7 0x412e9 0x32554199 0x324fb3fb 0x324fac51 0x32421305
>   0x3209d31b 0x32098b3f 0x320989d1 0x320983e5 0x320981f7 0x32091f1d
>   0x2fbbd039 0x2fbba9c7 0x2fbbad13 0x2fb25769 0x2fb2554b 0x34a926d3
>   0x32484891 0x4b9c9 0x3a886ab7) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

As you can see, the `_post.repost.group.name` does return a string. However, once I get to the second line, the application crashes with the error.

Would anyone happen to have any idea as to why this is occurring? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second line you wrote:

```
_post.group.name
```

instead of:

```
_post.repost.group.name
```

Enjoy ;)

Comment: Ah, shoot. Sometimes it's the little things that get you... Thanks!